# TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file: 'stalemate'

Tags: php, tcpdf, html2pdf

I have html that uses some script fonts that need to be converted to pdf. I have everything working on this, except when I try and include the script fonts in the pdf it gives the the following error:

```
TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file: 'stalemate'
```

The original font is from the Google Fonts library. Per instructions I have found, I renamed the font so that it was all lowercase, then made the matrix files using the ttf2ufm utility. I then took these files and used the makefont.php utility to make the needed files for the font to be included in the TCPDF font folder (stalemate.z, stalemate.ctg.z and stalemate.php). I have also tried putting them in a specific folder and pointing the call to that as well.

Seems like I have all the right files in all the right places and still get the above error. If I take out the style for that font on the html, the document PDFs just fine.

I have made a smaller test page at http://mattodesigns.com/pdfconverter.php, which take the html from http://mattodesigns.com/sample.html and converts it to a pdf. The following is the php code:

```
<?php
require_once 'html2pdf_v4.03/html2pdf.class.php';

$url = 'http://mattodesigns.com/sample.html';
$source = file_get_contents($url);
$html   = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\t"), '', $source);
$orientation    = 'P';
$format     = 'A4';
$margins = array(0,0,0,0);

$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF($orientation, $format, 'en', true, 'UTF-8', $margins);
$html2pdf->addFont('stalemate', '', 'stalemate.php');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$html2pdf->Output('first_PDF_file.pdf');

?>
```

The HTML code that it pulls is:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    @font-face {font-family: "stalemate"; font-weight: 400; src: url(/fonts/stalemate.otf) format("opentype");}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Make Sure this is working</h1>
<p style="font-family: 'stalemate', cursive ;">This is your first PDF File</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on this would be great.

Comment: Don't know if you already resolved this but take a look at http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf:en:v4:font